# How to send home page of wordpress website as a newsletter to subscribers?

Tags: mailing-list

How to send home page of wordpress website as a newsletter to subscribers? Is it possible?

I want to send some part of home page as a newsletter on weekly basis

Comment: What you mean as home page? Your new post on home page?

Comment: No, all component of home page A new post + comments + Sidebar. I want to send all as a static newsletter

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to create a separate template the mimics your homepage (make it private), but that is formatted differently to fit the requirements of a html newsletter (i.e. inline css, etc...), because they have different standards. Then just copy the page's html and drop it into your favorite newsletter tool.

Comment: but mark of newsletter is dfferent. in newsletter we still use tables

Comment: I know, you would have to rebuild the homepage in the template using tables and html e-mail compliant code. Obviously it's not the most convenient thing to do, but that's the way I have done it. After the initial build is done it works like a charm. Anyone else know of a better solution?

Comment: Taking a big screenshot.